# Why are faithful actions called faithful and who first called them faithful?

Tags: terminology, group-theory

This is a cross post from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3647129/272127)

I want to know *why* are faithful actions called faithful and *who* first called them  faithful?

**Definition:** An action $G$ on $X$ is faithful when ${g_1 \neq g_2  \Rightarrow  g_1 x \neq g_2 x}$ for some ${x \in X}$ (different elements of $G$ act differently at some point).

Comment: Has been answered on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/359121/90655).